# Code: TokenNotFound Message: User not found in token cache. Maybe the server was restarted

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have the following function to call users from active directory use graph api.
This function is hit on each keyup of a text box. But i am getting following error

> Code: TokenNotFound Message: User not found in token cache. Maybe the
>   server was restarted.

at the line

```
var user = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

Entire function Below:

```
     public async Task<string> GetUsersJSONAsync(string textValue)
            {
               // email = email ?? User.Identity.Name ?? User.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
                var identifier = User.FindFirst(Startup.ObjectIdentifierType)?.Value;
                var graphClient = _graphSdkHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient(identifier);
                string usersJSON = await GraphService.GetAllUserJson(graphClient, HttpContext, textValue);
                return usersJSON;
            }


    public static async Task<string> GetAllUserJson(GraphServiceClient graphClient, HttpContext httpContext, string textValue)
            {
               // if (email == null) return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = "Email address cannot be null." }, Formatting.Indented);

                try
                {
                    // Load user profile.
                    var user = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();                    
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user.Where(u => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.Surname) && ( u.Surname.ToLower().StartsWith(textValue) || u.Surname.ToUpper().StartsWith(textValue.ToUpper()))), Formatting.Indented);
                }
                catch (ServiceException e)
                {
                    switch (e.Error.Code)
                    {
                        case "Request_ResourceNotFound":
                        case "ResourceNotFound":
                        case "ErrorItemNotFound":
                        //case "itemNotFound":
                        //    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = $"User '{email}' was not found." }, Formatting.Indented);
                        //case "ErrorInvalidUser":
                        //    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = $"The requested user '{email}' is invalid." }, Formatting.Indented);
                        case "AuthenticationFailure":
                            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { e.Error.Message }, Formatting.Indented);
                        case "TokenNotFound":
                            await httpContext.ChallengeAsync();
                            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { e.Error.Message }, Formatting.Indented);
                        default:
                            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = "An unknown error has occured." }, Formatting.Indented);
                    }
                }
            }


 // Gets an access token. First tries to get the access token from the token cache.
        // Using password (secret) to authenticate. Production apps should use a certificate.
        public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync(string userId)
        {
            _userTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(userId, _memoryCache).GetCacheInstance();

            var cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
                _appId,
                _redirectUri,
                _credential,
                _userTokenCache,
                null);

            if (!cca.Users.Any()) throw new ServiceException(new Error
            {
                Code = "TokenNotFound",
                Message = "User not found in token cache. Maybe the server was restarted."
            });

            try
            {
                var result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_scopes, cca.Users.First());
                return result.AccessToken;
            }

            // Unable to retrieve the access token silently.
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new ServiceException(new Error
                {
                    Code = GraphErrorCode.AuthenticationFailure.ToString(),
                    Message = "Caller needs to authenticate. Unable to retrieve the access token silently."
                });
            }
        }
```

Can you help whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is 4 months old - is this still an issue for you?

As the previous respondent pointed out, the error you're seeing is being thrown in the catch block in your code meant to handle an empty users collection.

In case you're stuck on this, or anyone else comes here - if you used [this sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample/blob/master/MicrosoftGraphAspNetCoreConnectSample/Helpers/GraphSDKHelper.cs) (or using `ConfidentialClientApplication` in any respect) and are throwing this exception, it's because your _userTokenCache has no users*. Of course, it's not because your AD has no users, otherwise you wouldn't be able to authenticate. Most likely, it is because a stale cookie in your browser is being passed as the access token to your authProvider. You can use Fiddler (or just check your localhost browser cookies) to find it (should be called AspNetCore.Cookies, but you may want to clear all of them).

If you're storing the tokencache in session (as the example is), remember that each time you start and stop the application, your working memory will be thrown out so the token provided by your browser will no longer match the new one your application will retrieve upon starting up again (unless, again, you've cleared the browser cookies).

*`cca.Users` is no longer used or supported by MSAL - you have to use `cca.GetAccountsAsync()`. If you have a deployed application running with the deprecated `IUser` implementation, you'll have to change this. Otherwise, in development your compiler will complain and not let you build, so you'll already know about this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it seems some chunks of logic are missing. For example, you got the method

```
public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync(string userId)
```

but I can't see where this is being called. Besides that, I don't see the code for fetching a token from Azure AD either. Lastly, the error message you mention

> Code: TokenNotFound Message: User not found in token cache. Maybe the server was restarted.

Seems like the error you're throwing

```
if (!cca.Users.Any()) throw new ServiceException(new Error
{
     Code = "TokenNotFound",
     Message = "User not found in token cache. Maybe the server was restarted."
});
```

Since the code isn't complete, I will try and make an assumption on what might be going wrong.

Firstly, assuming you're using MSAL.Net, a step in the acquisition of a token is missing.

The general flow is (Using `GetTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync()`)

> 1. Client challenges the user
> 2. User gets redirected and logs in
> 3. Callback is called and the client receives a `code` from the login process
> 4. Pass the code to `GetTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync()` to obtain an id_token and depending on the permissions an access token.
>      `GetTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync()` will store the token in the cache
>      that has been provided to the `ConfidentialClientApplication`
> 5. Retrieve the token from the cache with `AcquireTokenSilentAsync()`
> 6. If we fail to retrieve a token from the cache with `AcquireTokenSilentAsync()`, we'll request a new one from via
>      `AcquireTokenAsync()`

Most of this flow seems to be in place in your code, but it could be you're missing the actual token acquisition. Since no token is retrieved, no user is added to the `ConfidentialClientApplication`, which means `cca.Users.Any()` returns false, resulting in an `ServiceError`

Assuming the whole flow is in place, and you're actually acquiring a token, my second assumption would be that the `_memoryCache` are different. The _memoryCache in which you saved your token differs from the one you use to acquire a token silently.

I would recommend reading [the documentation on token acquisition](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-Tokens) to determine the type of retrieving is the right fit for your application.

**EDIT**

Actually, I assume your code is inspired by this [example](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample/blob/master/MicrosoftGraphAspNetCoreConnectSample/Helpers/GraphSDKHelper.cs). 
What's especially interesting is this part

```
public GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient(string userId)
    {
        _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        async requestMessage =>
        {
            // Passing tenant ID to the sample auth provider to use as a cache key
            var accessToken = await _authProvider.GetUserAccessTokenAsync(userId);
         ...
        }
        return _graphClient;
    }
```

What seems to be happening is that calling `var user = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();` invokes the delegate that is provided to the GraphServiceClient. This in turn calls `_authProvider.GetUserAccessTokenAsync(userId);` which brings us to the `public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync(string userId)` method. Our error most likely originates here, due to no Users being present in the `ConfidentialClientApplication.Users` collection

Hope this helps!