# Microsoft Graph: "Request_ResourceNotFound" vs. "ResourceNotFound" vs. "ErrorItemNotFound" vs. "ItemNotFound"

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Our application "syncs" user data from the `AzureAD` to our database and I noticed that some requests fail with the following error:

> Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
>   Message: Resource 'S-1-5-21-2428866552-2013070483-421003753-10106' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

The error itself makes sense, because this entry is not part of our `Azure AD`.

To ensure a proper error handling I studied the documentation and got confused: Where is `Request_ResourceNotFound` documented? The code itself is not listed in the [Graph Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors) and I found quite a few different Stackoverflow questions or GitHub issues with "similar", but different error codes, e.g. [error code "ResourceNotFound"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082087/microsoft-graph-error-resourcenotfound-message-resource-could-not-be-disco) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629279/resourcenotfound-microsoft-graph-api-with-correct-token) or [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/5291) and then I found this [Stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171836/code-tokennotfound-message-user-not-found-in-token-cache-maybe-the-server-was) which has catches quite a few similar error codes:

```
  switch (e.Error.Code)
                    {
                        case "Request_ResourceNotFound":
                        case "ResourceNotFound":
                        case "ErrorItemNotFound":
                        //case "itemNotFound":
                        //    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = $"User '{email}' was not found." }, Formatting.Indented);
                        ...
                    }
```

The [.NET SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph/Enums/GraphErrorCode.cs) lists also some error codes, but `Request_ResourceNotFound` is somehow missing.

I understand that the Graph is an umbrella for different products, but are there some general error codes or (in case of users) which one is the "correct" error code for "user not found"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP has a standard error code for "not found".  I would recommend using

```
e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound
```

and then there will be no confusion.  If you have special handling for specific known error codes, then check for that code as a secondary test.  This avoids needing to test for all possibilities of the code.